# Teams recording bot MS Teams

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to run the sample code for Teams-recording bot on my local machine, given here - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/AksSamples/teams-recording-bot but getting some errors.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqSz8.png)

Comment: As if it missed SDK refereces on your project, did you rebuilt or seen which reference you are missing?

Comment: Yes I rebuilt the solution but facing the same issue

Comment: It seems your project location is little deeper than the patent drive for example `C://Folder/Folder/Folder/Folder/YourProject` , another issue check your project reference file and ensure you have `recordingBot.service.dll` there.

Comment: Ya , I can't find the recordingBot.service.dll file

Comment: So download `recordingBot.service.dll` from nuget and rebuild the project